# VisualStudio 2019: Server Explorer problem after update to version 16.11.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Last night I update my VS2019 to last version and after that I got the below error when I go to Server Explorer in my all ASP .Net MVC projects.

When I try to open my database connection from below picture:

[image: Server explorer]

I got this error:

[image: Error message]

this error occurred exactly after update...

Comment: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Configure-TableAdapter-failed/1505411

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this provider assembly from previous studio version.
Place attached file (from studio version 16.10.4) to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE folder of your installation.

https://sendvsfeedback2-download.azurewebsites.net/api/fileBlob/file?name=Bca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip&tid=ca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050

Comment: Thanks, It works, hope to does not have any conflict with other .dlls

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why the upgrade of the dll. There must be a reason and hope i dont crazy with errors related to this upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same error. It seems that it is happened due to **the latest update 16.11.1**.

For now, alternatively, I solved the problem by removing the current **Microsoft SQL Server** data connection, and add **Microsoft ODBC Data Source** instead.

[image]

Enter your **connection string** or **build** it.

Comment: what do you mean by connection string? Can you please give an example?

Comment: Use another option **"Use user name or system data source name:"**. you can find your database engine in the drop down (try refresh), then enter **User name** and **Password**. Use SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: [The Connection Strings Reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) -- this link helps you to find your connection string. For you it might be work: `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;` Consider you have to replace **Server, Database, User(Uid) and Password(Pwd)**.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different method of how to do it. where it says datasource click change and where it says data provider change it to ole db here I just made a video for this for me for my future lol
[Fixed it video](https://youtu.be/SZWnYHGJ_Dk)