# What is this error? "Unable to add data connection. Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture."

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to add a data connection to my project but everytime I add a new data connection I keep getting this error message:

[image: Error Message]

I have repaired and restarted Visual Studio but I still keep getting this message. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Which exact version of Visual Studio? Have you checked the develop community and the release notes of Visual Studio?

Comment: Seems to be related to [VisualStudio 2019: Server Explorer problem after update to version 16.11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814492/visualstudio-2019-server-explorer-problem-after-update-to-version-16-11-1)

Comment: Why did he get two votes down. Non of the other answers to this question are relevant and I am looking for this same in formation. Most answers are about 2 plus more years ago and not even the exact error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VisualStudio 2019: Server Explorer problem after update to version 16.11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814492/visualstudio-2019-server-explorer-problem-after-update-to-version-16-11-1)

Comment: I think that version 16.11.2 solves the issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.11.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in a most recent release version of Visual Studio.  Details, work around, and plan to fix here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate/1505966

Namely, the work around is to copy Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer from the previous good version into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE.  You can find this file here: https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip&tid=ca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050.

Per the link above: "A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release."

Comment: I'll take a look but I can simply just connect to the database using connection strings in ASP.Net Core. I'll let you know in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Some community version of visual studio shows this type of error so just click on below link
"https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip&tid=ca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050."
and download after select the file and paste into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: That link doesn't look necessarily trustworthy.