# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture SQL connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a question. I created an ASP.NET MVC project. Now I want to include my database in the project but I get the error

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or neutral culture

I'm getting this error after Visual Studio update it didn't exist before.

How can I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VisualStudio 2019: Server Explorer problem after update to version 16.11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814492/visualstudio-2019-server-explorer-problem-after-update-to-version-16-11-1)

Comment: I tried adding it but it didn't accept.

Comment: @mervedeepika: What you do to include your database to your project? Did you try to use the _Entity Data Model Wizard_ to generate the **_ADO.NET Entity Data Model_** to your project?